# Tetrahedron volume

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

How to calculate volume of tetrahedron given lengths of all it's edges?

Comment: This is really the kind of thing you should've Googled first.

Comment: http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/courses/m308/projects/cchang/webpages/tetrahedron.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Cayley-Menger Determinant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cayley-MengerDeterminant.html) - A generalization of Herons Formula.